# Substract hours without having a date

Tags: r

I have two columns that contain start time and end time. Now I need to know what the difference is and put in a new column.

All resources and questions I have read have a date like `2019/11/11` but then you can use the `difftime()` function.

How ever, I do not have a date. I only have two times.
Example data:

```
Activity Time.start Time.end
a        08:45:00   11:45:00
b        09:30:00   10:30:00
```

Which I would like to be the difference in a new column:

```
 Activity Time.start Time.end  Diff
 a        08:45:00   11:45:00  3
 b        09:30:00   10:30:00  1
```

Comment: convert to `as.POSIXct`, i.e. (`as.POSIXct(df$Time.start, format = '%H:%M:%S')`) and use `difftime`.

Comment: Do you just want the hours difference, and are you rounding them? In your first example, you have `b` having a `Time.start` of 09:15:00, and then it's 09:30:00

Comment: @Matt that's my bad. It doesn't have to be rounded. I think I copied activity C as that starts at 9:30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = data.frame(Activity = c("a", "b"), Time.start = c("08:45:00", "09:30:00"),
                Time.end = c("11:45:00", "10:30:00"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df$Time.start = strptime(df$Time.start, format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
df$Time.end = strptime(df$Time.end, format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
df$Diff = df$Time.end - df$Time.start
df
```

Or if you prefer a more compact `dplyr` solution

```
df = data.frame(Activity = c("a", "b"), Time.start = c("08:45:00", "09:30:00"),
                Time.end = c("11:45:00", "10:30:00"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

df = df %>% 
  mutate(Time.start = as.POSIXct(Time.start, format = "%H:%M:%S")) %>% 
  mutate(Time.end = as.POSIXct(Time.end, format = "%H:%M:%S")) %>% 
  mutate(Diff = Time.end - Time.start)
df
```

```
> df
  Activity          Time.start            Time.end    Diff
1        a 2020-04-03 08:45:00 2020-04-03 11:45:00 3 hours
2        b 2020-04-03 09:30:00 2020-04-03 10:30:00 1 hours
```

Comment: With your solution it works, only I get minutes instead of hours. So In the last mutate I used difftime with units= "hours" option

Answer (score 0):

You can use `difftime` and specify units:

```
df$new_column <- difftime(Time.start, Time.end, units = "hours")
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried it before. I get an error message saying "character string is not in a standard unabmiguous format"

Comment: Try setting up your time like this: `time1 <- as.POSIXct('2017-10-08T07:00:00z', format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")`